# Convert from varchar formatted as 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm stuck with the following. How do I convert strings that are formatted like the following into DateTime type?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('26/03/2012 00:00:00',10))
```

Error on the above is as follows:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Calling `CONVERT(char` on something that is *already* a string is an exercise in pointlessness. Where is this string coming from? Why has it now already been converted to `datetime`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've ameneded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `CONVERT` function with style 103 (`dd/mm/yyyy`), see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for further details.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'26/03/2012 00:00:00',103)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SET DATEFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx):

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

SELECT CAST('26/03/2012 00:00:00' AS DATETIME);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/390755)**</kbd>

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing connection settings when the problem can be solved in a more local fashion (via the *style* argument for `CONVERT`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree

Comment: @whytheq Where is the problem to set back to original after initial `INSERT` to table? Anyway you should provide dates in culture independent [**ISO 8601**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('26/03/2012 00:00:00', 10),105)
```